# Can't load sparks in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I installed sparks for CodeIgniter(v2.1.2) via command line. no errors. But I can't load sparks.

my code is

```
$this->load->spark('redis/0.4.1');
$this->redis->set("foo", "bar");
```

`$this->load->spark('redis/0.4.1');` returns true, so it should be loaded, but I get the error

```
[CIUnit] PHP Error: Notice - Undefined property: <myController>::$redis
```

also tried it with another spark, same error. Any help?